How to avoid redundant integration of apps script libraries in large apps script projects
I have a large apps script project which I tried to modularize by splitting the code into libraries. There is a core library which I use on the main project level as well as in the module libraries.
As far as I understood, apps script integrates the core library in the main project as well as in the module libraries.
This leads to redundant integrations of the same code and long start up times. The following example illustrates the principle:
Main.js

library: Core.js
library: ModuleA.js
library: ModuleB.js

ModuleA.js

library: Core.js

ModuleB.js

library: Core.js

Is there a way to have Core.js only once in the project (e.g. as a library in Main.js) and access it from Main.js, ModuleA.js and ModuleB.js ?

This question ris about software engineering, and need more focus. Are You using only the online editor?

Yes, I am using only the editor which Google provides for Apps Script projects. Actually I am familiar with software engineering concepts but I have found no work around to the described behavior of how apps script handles libraries.

First, please remember that Google Apps Script is a rapid development platform, not a full-fledged one. You likely need to use an advanced IDE to do what you want. This will allow you to use third-party tools to achieve your design goals. This might lead you to split your large app into multiple small apps or look for another platform unless your project is an Editor Add-on, and in such case, you might have to evaluate if you are putting too much into it.

The Google Apps Script online IDE is limited compared to other IDEs like Visual Studio Code. Regarding managing projects as libraries, the Google Apps Script online IDE has very few features, like deployment as a library and support for a subset of JSDoc tags for automatically generating documentation and autocomplete.
You might use the Google Apps Script API to manage Google Apps Script projects, including libraries. One way is to use CLASP to clone a project locally or to a more advanced online IDE.
Please remember that each project has its own Property Service stores (User Properties, Script Properties). This means that if your libraries use this service, they can't access the stores of the other libraries, so you will have to create an interface for reading/writing at the other libraries' stores.
Considering the above, you might find that it's better to handle all the code in a single Google Apps Script project and the parts that might be reusable across projects, copy them using, i.e., CLASP.

Thank you for your reply. I am aware that I am stretching the online IDE to its limits. Currently I am hesitating to "migrate" to CLASP and a local IDE because the only problem that I currently have is the way that apps script seems to handle libraries. I am not sure if I understood you correctly. You say if I use CLASP I do not need to use libraries at all, because I can organize the code with the means of the local IDE and CLASP will merge everything into a huge single project. Is this correct ?

CLASP doesn't do "magic",  it's just a tool that can help with a few tasks, like "downloading" and "uploading" all the files of a Google Apps Script project, including libraries. Depending on your Google Apps Script filenaming practices you might have to rename the files before putting all of them in same Google Apps Script project. Advanced IDEs make easier to handle files than the online IDE, i.e., you might use bash to create a script to dowload all the projects "at once", check for duplicate filenames, rename the files when this be needed and put all the files in a single project.

I'm not saying that having a single project (no libraries) is the "correct" way to handle Google Apps Script projects, but this might be  the only way to avoid "integration redundancies". It depends on what your project does among other things.

Using libraries is not recommended for Google apps scripts. Unlike modules, libraries are entirely different projects hosted in a different url. Before starting the script, the project will download all the  different projects and will increase in significant delays. The official best practices documentation and library docs warns:

Warning: A script that uses a library doesn't run as quickly as it would if all the code were contained within a single script project. Although libraries can make development and maintenance more convenient, use them sparingly in projects where speed is critical. Because of this issue, library use should be limited in add-ons.

Now,

Is there a way to have Core.js only once in the project (e.g. as a library in Main.js) and access it from Main.js, ModuleA.js and ModuleB.js ?

That depends on what each project does and what resources it accesses. Resources can be shared or not shared. If the resources you need are shared, and you don't actually need to run Module A or B independently outside of Main.js,  then I guess you only need Core.js in Main.js. You can also try passing the Core object around to the modules from Main as part of a initialization process.

Thank you for your reply! Can you please explain the last sentence in a little bit more detail? I mainly need the functions which are in my module libraries. How can I pass the core library as an object to the modules?

@draude74 I haven't tested this, but in Main, const data = ModuleA.initialization(Core), where Core is the core library and ModuleA is a library and the function in it which initializes it is like function initialization(Core){do stuff with Core}
